# Publishing projects with subproject dependencies to maven by using Gradle maven-publish plugin

Tags: java, android, gradle, multi-module, maven-publish

I have a gradle multiproject with the following structure:

```
root
│
├── core-library
│   └── build.gradle
│
├── additional-feature-library
│   │
│   ├── entities
│   │   └── build.gradle
│   │
│   └── build.gradle
│
├── sample-android-app
│   └── build.gradle
│
├── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

settings.gradle:

```
include(":core-library")
include(":additional-feature-library")
include(":additional-feature-library:entities")
include(":sample-android-app")
```

additional-feature-library/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id("java-library")
    id("kotlin")
    id("maven-publish")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":additional-feature-library:entities"))
    implementation(project(":core-library"))

    // ... other dependencies from maven
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = "com.example"
            artifactId = "additional-feature-library"
            version = "1.0.0"

            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute task additional-feature-library/publishToMavenLocal, it generates *.jar file with classes from additional-feature-library and POM with the following dependencies:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>root.additional-feature-library</groupId>
      <artifactId>entities</artifactId>
      <version>unspecified</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>root</groupId>
      <artifactId>core-library</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The problem is that these dependencies don't exist (actually core-library will be published to maven). I would like to remove dependency produced by subproject additional-feature-library/entities and include classes from that subprject into *.jar file. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this as well.